# How to assign data categories to articles using apex controller?

Tags: apex, knowledge, data-category

I am trying to assign data categories to knowledge base articles records. I am using articlename_DataCategorySelection to define the assignment and then to inset it. 
The object to be inserted as follows:

```
DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult[] results = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(
    new String[] { 'KnowledgeArticleVersion'}
); 
tempCat = new MSDS__DataCategorySelection ();
tempCat.DataCategoryGroupName = results[0].getName();  // key line
tempCat.DataCategoryName = 'Latin America'; //m.Category_Path__c;
tempCat.ParentId = m.id;
```

Above, `results[0]` is of type `DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult` --that contains data category group description. but it is not allowing me to insert the record successfully.

While running the code above, I get an error:

> INVALID_DATA_CATEGORY_GROUP_REFERENCE, invalid data category group referenced

It seems the `DataCategoryGroupName` is not handled properly. Does anyone know what value to assign to that field?

Comment: It may be that `DataCategoryName` is the real culprit. If you go to `DataCategorySetup`, do you see `Latin America` as an actual subcategory of what you end up using from `results[0]`?

Comment: got it. i was setting up latin america , it should have an underscore sign. thanks you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be getting this error based on `DataCategoryName`, not `DataCategoryGroupName`. Double-check that `Latin America` is a valid category for the category group you selected based on `results[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading in a way

Salesforce takes the value in the `DataCategoryName` and then looks to see if it can be found in the associated `DataCategoryGroupName`. If it doesn't find it, the error

```
INVALID_DATA_CATEGORY_GROUP_REFERENCE, invalid data category group referenced
```

is generated which makes you think you screwed up in the specification of `DataCategoryGroupName`, or swapped data category names for groups and vice-versa.

A typical cause of this error is that  `DataCategoryName` is the Data Categories API name, so, if using Apex or Data Loader, it is easy to forget this, especially if you are using the recommended Data Category Groups:

- Products
- Geos
- Customer Types

where real world Data Category Names (labels) may have spaces such as in your OP `Latin America`. Its API name is `Latin_America`